# How to combine two urls as Regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I used 
`pattern = re.compile(r'(\/\/smtgvs\.weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.[jpng]*)')` to find all urls, now I found there are some urls `\/\/smtgvs\.cdn\.weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.[jpng]*)')`

How can I combine these two patterns? I tried `pattern = re.compile(r'(\/\/smtgvs\[.cdn]*\.weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.[jpng]*)')`

That seems like not correct...

Comment: You may use: `pattern = re.compile(r'//smtgvs(?:\.cdn)?\.weathernews\.jp/s/topics/img/\d+/\w+\.(?:png|jpe?g)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern should work:

```
\/\/smtgvs\.(?:cdn)*\.*weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.[jpng]*
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/i8a1tQ/2